# Is there a word for someone who is a lover of the incidental or coincidence?

Tags: single-word-requests

Bit of a weird one. I'm trying to write a song at the moment and I have the subject sorted but now I want to find out if there is a word for it.

I find myself tending to like melodies and lyrics that I come up with by accident or through coincidence than through actual structured song writing and was wondering if there was a word for this. If so I have a song title and also a bit more background to work with for the lyrics.

Comment: Wow. A huge amount of thanks to everyone here for their suggestions! You've all given me an incredible amount to go with from here on in. I will probably start spending a lot of time on this site from now on. Really appreciate the help! :)

Answer (score 10):

Are you thinking of *serendipitous*?

> **serendipity** |ˌserənˈdipitē|
>   *noun*
>   the occurrence and development of events by chance in a happy or beneficial way : *a fortunate stroke of serendipity* | *a series of small*

Otherwise, maybe you are thinking of *aleatoric* composition?

> **aleatory** |ˈālēəˌtôrē; ˈal-|
>   *adjective*
>   depending on the throw of a die or on chance; random.
>   • relating to or denoting music or other forms of art involving elements of random choice (sometimes using statistical or computer techniques) during their composition, production, or performance.

I suspect you mean the former, but it's not entirely clear to me from your question.

[Source: New Oxford American Dictionary]

Comment: I had thought of serendipitous but it doesn't quite cover what I mean. Aleatory may be closer...I'm looking for something that describes someone who likes art and music more because their creation came about through serendipity/aleatoric nature. Does that make more sense??

Comment: +1 for serendipitous. I think a "serendipitous artist" would fit the description and clarification.

Comment: I’m sure those citations came from somewhere, but I don’t know where. :(

Comment: @tchrist: Fixed. 'Twas a simpler time when I just quoted without linking sometimes because I couldn't link to the NOAD on my Mac.

Answer (score 3):

Frankly, for a song title, I think you will be better off looking for an allegory rather than a word that means literally what you describe.

Now I suppose if a person enjoys the ups and downs of being blown by the wind then ***tumbleweed*** might fit the bill.

If the person sails the ocean in hope of floating delights then ***treasure hunter*** or ***pirate*** might work.

If one indiscriminately filters everything through their body looking for edible protein then they might be a ***whale***.

But now this is getting ridiculous, and I hardly think I've helped you.

Answer (score 1):

"Happy-go-lucky" or "Devil-may-care"

Answer (score 1):

Something in your question brought to mind the concept of *The Muse*. This led me to the concept of the [*Muse-poet*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muse#The_Muse-poet). It may be not quite right, but perhaps you could use something *muse*-like:

> **muse**:  a woman, or a force personified as a woman, who is the source of inspiration for a creative artist.

<sup>*-NOAD*</sup>

Comment: +1; _Muse_ is a great word for this; you could say, "My art follows the muse." I don't know how to transform _muse_ into an adjective, however.

Comment: Chris didn't ask for an adjective. Or rather, he didn't specify an adjective. A noun works too as long as either way they describe a person. The real problem is that he asked for a word for the artist, not the artist's inspiration.

Answer (score 0):

I would start with this list:

- chancy
- organic
- chaotic
- random
- unstructured
- unrestrained
- loose
- untethered

Of these, I think *organic* is the best.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on which dictionary you use, '***Dilettante***' might fit the bill.  Merriam-Webster says:

> 1: an admirer or lover of the arts 
>   2: a person having a superficial interest in an art or a branch of knowledge : *dabbler*

Wiktionary is a bit less flattering:

> 1. An amateur, someone who dabbles in a field out of casual interest rather than as a profession or serious interest.
> 2. A person with a general but superficial interest in any art or a branch of knowledge. (Sometimes derogatory.)

Two options for your question:

a. Serendipitous dilettante

b. A dilettante of serendipity.